# Is there a way to start the screensaver by clicking on something?

Tags: kubuntu

I am unable to suspend my Kubuntu 14.04.2 laptop because when I wake up from sleep mode the KDE doesn't function.  So instead of putting my laptop to sleep, I just let the screen turn black after 10 minutes of inactivity.  I want to trigger the screen to turn off by clicking a button, or an icon.  Is there some bash command I can run to turn off the screen?  And when I move the mouse, or type a letter on the keyboard, the screen will come back on?  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks for reading and replying!

Comment: What screensaver are you using? `xscreensaver`? `gnome-screensaver`?

Comment: I am using whatever screensaver comes default in Kubuntu 14.04.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Turn screen off**

The display can be turned off by a command:

```
xset dpms force off
```

About the command - man xset:

```
DESCRIPTION
       This program is used to set various user preference options of the display.


       -dpms   The -dpms option disables DPMS (Energy Star) features.

       +dpms   The +dpms option enables DPMS (Energy Star) features.

       dpms flags...
               The dpms option allows the DPMS (Energy Star) parameters to be set.  The option can take  up  to
               three  numerical values, or the `force' flag followed by a DPMS state.  The `force' flags forces
               the server to immediately switch to the DPMS state specified.  The DPMS  state  can  be  one  of
               `standby',  `suspend', `off', or `on'.  When numerical values are given, they set the inactivity
               period (in units of seconds) before the three modes are activated.  The first value given is for
               the  `standby'  mode, the second is for the `suspend' mode, and the third is for the `off' mode.
               Setting these values implicitly enables the DPMS features.  A value of zero disables a  particu‐
               lar mode.
```

**Turn the screen saver/locker on**

The KDE screen saver/locker can be turned on by command:

```
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /ScreenSaver SetActive true
```

The command will launch the screen saver or locking depending the user settings. KDE System Settings > Display and Monitor > Screen Locker.

[image]

About the qdbus - man qdbus:

```
NAME
       qdbus - a communication-interface for qt-based applications

SYNOPSIS
       qdbus [--system] [--literal] [servicename] [path] [method] [args]

DESCRIPTION
       qdbus provides an interface to Qt-based applications communicating over D-Bus.  See http://www.freedesk‐
       top.org/software/dbus/ for more information about the big picture.

       By default qdbus will list all service names of services that are running and you can manipulate at  the
       moment.  You can also manipulate and run several types of methods for each dbus-enabled application.
```

More: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/Introduction

**Command to button**

The KDE has the menu editor: https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/

After the command has a launch button the button can be transfered from the KDE menu to the desktop or to the panel.

Alternative is to add a plasma widget - On/Off Switch: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/On/Off%20Switch?content=116323

and add the plasma widget to the desktop/panel.

[image]

Binaries from the Ubuntu PPA: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=plasma-widget-on-off-switch

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was able to turn off my screen using the terminal command `xset dpms force off`.  I wrote a shell script (.sh file) with this command, made it executable by navigating to the directory I saved the shell script and executing the command `chmod +x yourfilenamehere.sh`.  Now I have an icon I can click on my desktop to turn off my screen; it's exactly what I wanted.  Once again, thanks so much!